# How does one prove $ZF\vDash MC\Rightarrow AC$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is somewhat adressed to **Andreas Blass**, whose papers I have read, in particular I make reference to an old paper of his »Existence of Basis implies the Axiom of Choice« (84). Anyone who happens to be informed may nevertheless feel free to enlighten me.

---

One works within $ZF$. Assume $MC$, that is, for all $X$ there exists $f:\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, so that for all $A\in\mathcal{P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ it holds $\emptyset\neq f(A)\subseteq A$ and $f(A)$ finite. To show is $AC$.

Due to $MC$ it holds

**Proposition 0.** Let $X$ be a set. There is a choice function $\mathcal{P}(X)\to X$ $\Longleftarrow$ $X$ is linear-orderable.

**Proof.** Consider a l.o. $\preceq$ on $X$. Set $m:\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ a multi-choice function. Then $c:\mathcal{P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}\to X$ defined by $c(A)=\min_{\preceq}m(A)$ is well-defined and a choice function. $\blacksquare$

Since one is working within $ZF$ it also holds:

**Proposition 1.** Let $X$ be a set. There is a choice function $\mathcal{P}(X)\to X$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $X$ is well-orderable. $\dashv$

**Corollary.** $X$ has choice $\Longrightarrow$ $X$ has a w.o. $\Longrightarrow$ $X$ has a l.o. $\Longrightarrow$ $X$ has choice. $\dashv$

It is thus necessary and sufficient to show, every set is linear-orderable. Again, since one is working within $ZF$, it is necessary and sufficient to just consider the sets $V_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in NO$ (the ordinal numbers).

An argument per induction *seems* to suggest itself. For the successor stages, one simply builds out of a well-order $\preceq$ on $V_{\alpha-1}$ a linear order (the lexical order, $\preceq_{lex}$) on $V_{\alpha}=\mathcal{P}(V_{\alpha-1})\equiv_{SET}{}^{V_{\alpha-1}}2$.

The argument encounters difficulty for limit-ordinals, since one cannot „choose“ a well-order for all the stages below it (except when the ordinal satisfies $cf(\alpha)<\alpha$). Consider simply $\alpha=\omega_{1}$, how would one construct a linear-order on $V_{\omega_{1}}$?

---

I should note: all authors I have read up until now each hold that $ZF\vDash MC\Rightarrow AC$.

---

**Final Remark.** I see now how to handle with successor stages in Frunobulax’ argument.

**Thm.** Assuming $ZF+MC$ every $V_{\alpha}$ is well-orderable.

**Proof.** Consider $\alpha\in NO$ any ordinal. Thanks to $MC$ there exists $m:\mathcal{P}(V_{\alpha})\to\mathcal{P}(V_{\alpha})$ a multi-choice function. This shall henceforth remain fixed.

As already mention it holds

**Claim.** for $X\subseteq V_{\alpha}$ and an LO $\preceq$ on $X$, using just $m$ and $\preceq$ one can *canonically* construct a choice function $\mathcal{P}(X)\to X$ (via. $c:A\mapsto \min_{\preceq}(m(A))$ for $A\neq\emptyset$) and out of *this* in turn *canonically* construct a WO of $X$ (utilising the recursion $x_{\gamma}:=c(X\setminus\{x_{\xi}:\xi<\gamma\})$ for $\gamma\in NO$ for as long as $X\supsetneq\{x_{\xi}:\xi<\gamma\}$). This canonically-definable well-order shall be denoted $\preceq^{m}$. $\dashv$

**Construction of a WO of $V_{\alpha}$.** One constructs recursively an increasing chain $(\preceq_{\beta})_{\beta\leq\alpha}$ of WO-s of the $V_{\beta}$:

- $\preceq_{0}:=\emptyset$.
- Limit stages: $\preceq_{\beta}:=\bigcup_{\xi<\beta}\preceq_{\xi}$.
- Successor stages: one linearly orders $R_{\beta}:=V_{\beta}\setminus V_{\beta-1}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(V_{\beta-1})\equiv{}^{V_{\beta-1}}2$ via the lexical-ordering $(\preceq_{beta-1})_{lex}$. Note that $R_{\beta}\subseteq V_{\alpha}$. Set $\preceq^{\ast}:=(\preceq_{beta-1})_{lex}^{m}$ a well-order. The well-orders are then patched together by placing everything in $R_{\beta}$ after $V_{\beta-1}$, to obtain a well-order of $V_{\beta-1}\sqcup R_{\beta}=V_{\beta}$.

This recursion is well-define and in particular $\preceq_{\alpha}$ witnesses the well-orderability of $V_{\alpha}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: For the result that $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ being well-orderable for all ordinals $\alpha$ gives choice, this has been asked here a few times. Or see [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/502-equivalents-of-the-axiom-of-choice/). You may want to remark explicitly that your proposition 0 is not being proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone, where it is false.

Comment: There are copious amounts of models of $\sf ZF$ with linearly ordered sets which are not well-orderable. For example the Dedekind-finite set of reals in Cohen's first model; $\Bbb R$ in Solovay's model and in models of $\sf AD$; and so on and so forth.

Comment: »You may want to remark explicitly that your proposition 0 is not being proved in  alone, where it is false.« I know, that is why it is written directly above Proposition 0 »Due to MC it holds«. The Corollary below Proposition 1 is within the assumptions of the Argument (*i.~e.* inclusive MC).

Answer (score 1):

If that's OK with you, it's easy to show that $\textbf{MC}$ implies
the antichain principle which is known to be equivalent to the axiom
of choice:

Let $X$ be a set [partially ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) by $R$, i.e. $R$ is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.  Let $f$ be a function
which assigns to each non-empty subset $A$ of $X$ a finite non-empty
subset $f(A)$ of $A$.  For each such $A$ the set
of $R$-minimal elements of $f(A)$ is finite,
non-empty and an $R$-antichain.  We'll call it $A'$.

Now, inductively, define $C_\alpha$ to be the set of all elements of
$X$ which are $R$-incomparable with all elements of $B_\beta$ for all
$\beta<\alpha$ and let $B_\alpha$ be $C_\alpha'$ (or $\emptyset$ if
$C_\alpha$ is empty).

The union of all $B_\alpha$ is a maximal $R$-antichain.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. The idea is good, but contains a technical failure: $A’$ may be empty! Consider an Equivalence relation, and suppose $f(A)$ consists of more than one element out of the same equivalence class, then $A’$ is empty.

Comment: A partial order which at the same time is an equivalence relation?  That leaves only one choice and its equivalence classes only have one element each...

Comment: The partial orders to be considered are simply: **transitive+reflexive** (do not necc. satisfy $x\leq y\leq x\Rightarrow y=x$). Here the proof that max-antichain-principle $\Longrightarrow$ AC: Let $X$ be a set. Let $P:=\{(a,A):a\in A\subseteq X\}$ and define $(a,A)\leq(a',A')$ iff $A'=A$. Then a maximal antichain corresponds to a choice function. (Notice, that this is an equivalence relation.)

Comment: I stand corrected! I see now, how your Version of max-Antichain-Principle also allows for a proof of $AC$: Let $X$ be a set of non-empty pairwise disjoint sets. Consider $\mathbb{P}:=\{(x,A)|\exists{B\in X:~}x\in A\subseteq B\}$ p.o. by $(x,A)<(x',A')$ iff $A\subset A'$ strict. Thus $<$ is transitive and non-refl. Observation: $(x,A)\perp (x',A')$ iff $A\cap A'=\emptyset$. Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be a maximal antichain for $\mathbb{P}$. Observation: $\forall{B\in X:~}\exists{!(x_{B},A_{B})\in\mathcal{C}:~}A_{B}\subseteq B$, which gives rise to a choice function $B\in X\mapsto x_{B}$.

Comment: Ach! Nee, the above does not work. I think the proof $Antichain-Principle\Longrightarrow AC$ really works with $(\mathbb{P},\leq)$ satisfying simply transitive+reflexive. In which case the problem remains, that $A’$ is not necessarily an antichain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of a proof by Rubin which builds on what you
already have above:

We claim that $\textbf{MC}$ implies that all $\mathbf{V}_\alpha$ can
be well-ordered.

So, let $\alpha$ be some fixed arbitrary ordinal.  Let $\lambda$ be
the smallest ordinal which can't be mapped one-to-one into
$\mathbf{V}_\alpha$ (i.e. the [Hartogs number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) of $\mathbf{V}_\alpha$).
$\lambda$ is well-ordered by $\in$, so we can define a linear order
$\preccurlyeq$ on ${\cal P}(\lambda)$ by $x
\preccurlyeq y$ iff $x=y$ or $x\neq y$ and $\min(x\bigtriangleup
y)\in x$ (where $\bigtriangleup$ is the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)).

As you've shown above, due to $\textbf{MC}$ we'll find a choice
function for ${\cal P}(\lambda)$ which in turn implies that this set
can be well-ordered.  We fix one well-ordering
of ${\cal P}(\lambda)$ for the rest of the proof.

Now let $R_\beta$ be the set of all $x\in{\mathbf V}_\alpha$ with [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe)
$\beta$.
If we can show, that all $R_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ can be
well-ordered, then it is obvious how we can combine these
well-orderings to get one for ${\mathbf V}_\alpha$.  So, we'll
inductively define well-orderings $\preccurlyeq_\beta$ of $R_\beta$:

Pick $\beta<\alpha$ and assume that for $\gamma<\beta$ a well-ordering
$\preccurlyeq_\gamma$ of $R_\gamma$ has already been defined.  Using
these, we can define an "obvious" well-ordering $<_\beta$ of ${\mathbf
  V}_\beta$ (being the disjoint union of the $R_\gamma$ for
$\gamma<\beta$).

There's a unique ordinal $\delta_\beta$ such that
$(\mathbf{V}_\beta,<_\beta)$ is isomorphic to $(\delta_\beta,\in)$ and
correspondingly there's a unique isomorphism $g_\beta$ from
$(\delta_\beta,\in)$ onto $(\mathbf{V}_\beta,<_\beta)$.  As $g_\beta$
is also an injection from $\delta_\beta$ into $\mathbf{V}_\alpha$, we
must have $\delta_\beta<\lambda$.

Now, for an element $x$ of $R_\beta$ we have $x\subseteq{\mathbf
  V}_\beta$ and thus $g_\beta^{-1}[x] \subseteq \delta_\beta \subseteq
\lambda$.  Thus, $g_\beta$ (or rather its inverse) gives us a natural
way of "projecting" a part of the above-mentioned well-ordering of ${\cal P}(\lambda)$
to $R_\beta$ which finishes our proof.

The important thing to note here is that we didn't make a choice at
each $\beta<\alpha$ stage.  The only choice made was right at the
beginning when we fixed a well-ordering of ${\cal P}(\lambda)$.

Comment: Hmmm, this is really sketchy at a critical step. **»[$\forall{x\in R_\beta:~}x\subseteq{\mathbf
  V}_\beta$, thus $g_\beta^{-1}[x] \subseteq \delta_\beta \subseteq \lambda$.  Thus, $g_\beta$ ... gives us a natural way of "projecting" a part of the above-mentioned well-ordering of ${\cal P}(\lambda)$ to $R_\beta$ which finishes our proof.]«** Problem: $g_{\beta}$ ist not necessarily uniquely/naturally choosable. There are more than one Bijektions from $R_{\beta}\to\delta_{\beta}$, since one may simply permute the elements of $R_{\beta}$.

Comment: Also it is not due to $MC$, that »$X$ has a WO $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has choice«, but rather due to $ZF$ (or other suitable basic axioms). It is due to $MC$ that »$X$ has a WO $\Leftrightarrow$ $X$ has a LO«.

Comment: No, that's wrong.  At that point of the construction $<_\beta$ is well-defined and, as I wrote, there's a _unique_ ordinal and a _unique_ isomorphism.  That's a standard theorem of set theory.  The mapping is between $\mathbf{V}_\beta$ and $\delta_\beta$, not between $R_\beta$ and $\delta_\beta$, and it is uniquely determined by the well-ordering.

Comment: For your second comment, see what @AndresCaicedo wrote above.  This can _not_ be proved in ZF alone.  I'll repeat that step of the proof in detail: $\lambda$ is well-ordered because it's an ordinal.  Using this well-ordering I construct a linear ordering on ${\cal P}(\lambda)$.  You've shown above that with MC we now have that ${\cal P}(\lambda)$ has a choice function (the choice function being a function from ${\cal P}({\cal P}(\lambda))$ to ${\cal P}(\lambda)$). This is equivalent to ${\cal P}(\lambda)$ being well-orderable.

Comment: Maybe there's some confusion here: $X$ can be well-ordered is of course equivalent to $X$ having a choice function in ZF - _if_ the choice function for $X$ is meant to be a function from ${\cal P}(X)$ to $X$.  I've explicitly used your own terminology from your question above.  Note that there's a big difference then between "$X$ has a choice function" and "${\cal P}(X)$ has a choice function".

Comment: @Comment 3: Yes, I am fully aware of this basic fact. I was disputing, that your recursion provides an ordering. Your recurison breaks down at successor stages (where one has to build $\preceq_{\beta}$ out of $\preceq_{\beta-1}$: this works, as we alread agree with a multi-choice function in combination with the lexical-ordering on the powerset, only the multi-choice function is not choosable at each stage.

Comment: Well, I've wasted enough time on this already and I certainly don't feel the desire to be insulted.  I maintain that both my answers are correct.  I suggest you go to a library and read for example Rubin's second book about AC.

Comment: Okay, I now understand how the induction-step work (and yes, of course, every stage is really just a successor-stage). You order $V_{\beta}$ via the orders on the $R_{\xi}$ for $\xi<\beta$, and then oder $R_{\beta}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(V_{\beta})$ via the natural projection onto the order of $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$. The problem I was seeing was due to my confusing $R_{\beta}:=V_{\beta+1}\setminus V_{\beta}$ with the »false« definition I used above $R_{\beta}:=V_{\beta}\setminus\bigcup_{\xi<\beta}V_{\xi}$.

Comment: Looking at this again years on, I fail to see where I ‘insulted’ Frunobulax. Is persistent inquiry of the subject matter—without any ad hominems—insulting? What a bizarre reaction.